# How to start and stop mysql server using cmd in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

I want to start and stop mysql server from command line in windows OS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go over [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is not a question but a statement. You should read the [tour] and the article [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To Start:

```
C:\Users\MariaDB - mysqld 10.1.37\bin\mysqld.exe
```

To Stop:

```
C:\Users\MariaDB - mysqld 10.1.37\bin\mysqladmin.exe -u root shutdown
```

Answer (score 0):

Admin PowerShell:

> `**Get-Service -Name mysql***`

shows: MySQL80 so START/STOP my sql server = runs -p 3***

> `**mysql -u root -p**`

> `**net stop MySQL80**`
> `**net start MySQL80**`

i just had an issue where the gui wouldn't start the server because i stopped it manually, then rebooted, tried to start with the gui it wouldn't start then with it stagnating in the background i opened elevated pwrShell `**net start mySQL80**`  it worked ,

OPEN WORKBENCH `**UNDER MENU ENTRY**'` `'Server>START/STOP SERVER'`